# Get datepicker and pass to url

Tags: php, jquery, datepicker

It is a datepicker. I need to pass selected date as parameters in php form url. 
The datepicker value is in jQuery. I got the selected date value through ajax and i posted as $_POST['from'] and $_POST['to'].

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var frm = $('#easy_widget_form');
    var first, second;
    first = $(".hasDatepicker[name=from]").val();
    second = $(".hasDatepicker[name=to]").val();
    //alert(first + " , " + second);

    first = $(".hasDatepicker[name=from]").datepicker('getDate');
    second = $(".hasDatepicker[name=to]").datepicker('getDate');
    //alert(first + " , " + second);

    jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "form_widget.php",    
            data: "first=" +first+"&second="+second,
            dataType: "text",
            success: function(){
                alert("Done");
            }
        });
}};
</script>
```

When i pass the date in url http://www.domain.com/?from=".$_POST['from']."&to=".$_POST['to']; it doesn't work.

**Error :** String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Here is my PHP

```
<form method="post" action="http://www.domain.com/?from=".$_POST['from']."&to=".$_POST['to']" name="easy_widget_form" id="easy_widget_form">
<input id="easy-widget-datepicker-from" type="text" name="from" value="20.04.2014" class="hasDatepicker">
<input id="easy-widget-datepicker-to" type="text" name="to" value="22.04.2014" class="hasDatepicker">           

<p class="easy-submit"><input type="submit" class="easybutton" value="Reserve now!"></p>                    
</form>
```

can someone help?

Comment: The `to` is missing an `=`. Why does your ajax has different parameters from the GET values?

Comment: Please show the PHP which is generating the error

Comment: Yes, i shown my php code.. pls chk

Comment: Normally, when i display S_POST['from'] and S_POST['to'] in form_widget.php, it works fine. When i pass these two in url, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

you are doing it wrong actually as far as I understand. If you use `ajax` for form submit why do you want to have that action url in form markup?

I would prefer to do like this

```
// point the request to necessary url
jQuery.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "http://www.domain.com/?from="+first+"&to="+second,
     success: function(response){
         // use the response accordingly 
     }
});
```

Hope this help

Comment: This is not working. The problem is, when i pass two variables in url, it is not working. Otherwise, when i use $_POST to display from date and to date, it is working